# XPATH required for an input text field where id is keep changing?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a text box in my web application, where I need to give input. I am trying to find the xpath of the text box. The following error is thrown:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" size="32" maxlength="128" id="yui_3_2_0_1_14845429655526105">
```

I want the `xpath` for textbox. here id is keep changing..

Comment: Exception log is not complete. Show full log or selector you've tried.

Comment: I tried with By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'yui_3_2_0_1_14845429655522')]" but it wont work.. exception log as follows,Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'

Comment: plz help me here to resolve my issue..

Answer (score 0):

You should try to wait some time until your element become visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]"));
element.sendKeys("text to send");
```

Comment: this is also not working it gives me Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'

Comment: not working....Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 25 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@type='text][starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'AWS-EPV6SRV2', ip: '10.100.1.140', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'

Comment: Andersson please provide me the solution on this?

Comment: Check whether there are more than one element matched `IList<IWebElement> allElements =  driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@type="text"][starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]")); allElements.size();` and whether your element located inside an `<iframe>`

Comment: I have checked, it is giving me the 0 count

Comment: If I used List<WebElement>allElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]")); 
  System.out.println(allElements.size()); it gives me 90 counts

Comment: And none `<input type="text">` elements? weird...check whether your element located inside `<iframe>`.  Check its ancestors: is there an `iframe`?

Comment: Andersson plz do some needful for me

Comment: I try :) **check whether your element located inside <iframe>**

Comment: looks like something wrong with this selector //input[@type='text], I checked element is not located inside the <iframe>

Comment: let me know ur mail id so I can send you the complete Overview of XML structure.

Comment: did u get xml structure?

Comment: Yep. Its not formatted, but ok, I'll try to check it

Comment: Actually my code works well with `"//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]"`... Now I get it :) You missed one single quote in `'text'`! this is how it looks on your `XPath`- `'text`... no closing quote! add it and code should work

Comment: List<WebElement>allElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id,'yui_')]")); System.out.println(allElements.size());

Comment: and what about `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]")).click();`?

Comment: this is also not working   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id, 'yui_')]
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'AWS-EPV6SRV2', ip: '10.100.1.140', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: Every attempt went to failure so Andersson what should I do?

Comment: Does your input field is actually visible when you just get the page in your browser or you need to scroll down to see it?

Comment: no need to scroll down it is visible while load the page in browser.

Comment: Is any other locator is there to find out that webelement?

Comment: Locator seem to be correct. Try to replace `visibilityOfElementLocated` with `presenceOfElementLocated`

Comment: I'm out of ideas :) Can you share `URL` of target page or it's commercial secret?

Comment: HI Andersson, hopefully u r fine did you have any updates on it?

Comment: I've tried everything possible to solve your problem :) Share URL

Comment: could you plz share ur mail id so that i can send you the details information with screenshot.

Comment: <td class="nowrapTd" id="yui_3_2_0_1_15127052261192312"><input size="32" maxlength="128" id="yui_3_2_0_1_15127052261192310" type="text"></td>